# How to make the detail description text in a table view editable?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

There are many applications like the one below where the detail description text is editable. How can one implement this look? And how can one retrieve the text that was entered?

[image]

Comment: I don't think that its a detail description text. It's a UITextField with placeholder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same impression we get using `UITextField` (using its place holder property). Custom cells having text fields should make this work.